# Programmatically setting Repeated Parameters in Scala

Tags: scala, language-features, variadic-functions

I'm trying to call `Futures.awaitAll` with a variable number of well... `Future`s. `awaitAll` is defined as `awaitAll(timeout : Long, fts : Future[Any]*)`. I have tried passing in a `List` and an `Array` but both won't work:

```
list = future1 :: future2 :: Nil

Futures.awaitAll(1000, list)

found : List[scala.actors.Future[Any]] required: scala.actors.Future[Any]
```

**EDIT:** What I now want to do is call `Futures.awaitAll` programmatically with a variable number of arguments (1 to n). So using `Futures.awaitAll(1000, future1, future2)` is not an option.

Chapter 8.8 of Programming in Scala didn't give me any hints how to solve this either, so help is welcome :)

Comment: This does get mentioned somewhere in PinS, but very briefly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using the * means that it's a vararg...it can take as many Future[Any] parameters as you add, but not a list/array of them.

So it's looking for a parameter list such as:

```
Futures.awaitAll(1000, future1, future2)
```

instead of

```
Futures.awaitAll(1000, list)
```

Edit: If you must have the ability to pass in Futures.awaitAll(1000, list), then try casting it.

So try this:

```
Futures.awaitAll(1000, list: _*)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Futures.awaitAll(1000, futures: _*)
```

should work (can't test it now). See 4.6.2 in the [Scala Language Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/sites/default/files/linuxsoft_archives/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf).